# Hide content from mobile version and make visible on desktop, using Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I tried to use the Tailwind `hidden` class to hide content from my page on mobile screens only, but instead it becomes hidden for desktop and visible in the mobile version. I want the opposite.

**My code:**

```html
<nav class="hidden lg:block">abc</nav>
```

I also tried to use the `visible` and `invisible` utility classes, but that didn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `sm` breakpoint for mobile screens. And assign below class to that coomponent.

```
class = "hidden sm:block"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="absolute inset-0 bg-slate-400 bg-center"></div>
  
  <div class="hidden sm:block relative bg-white px-6 pt-10 mt-10 pb-8 sm:mx-auto sm:max-w-lg sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">

  <!-- ignore this code of card -->
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-md">
      
      <div class="divide-y divide-gray-300/50">
        <div class="space-y-6 py-8 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
          
          <ul class="space-y-4">
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Customizing your
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">tailwind.config.js</code> file
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">
                Extracting classes with
                <code class="text-sm font-bold text-gray-900">@apply</code>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li class="flex items-center">
              <svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-none fill-sky-100 stroke-sky-500 stroke-2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
                <path d="m8 13 2.165 2.165a1 1 0 0 0 1.521-.126L16 9" fill="none" />
              </svg>
              <p class="ml-4">Code completion with instant preview</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- card code ends -->
  
  </div>
</div>
```

ANd you can also view the example [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/auHc6aAJuP?size=706x720)

Comment: How do you do that without explicitly specifying the `display` property? I was thinking about something like `:not(desktop):hidden`. The reason I'm asking is because when you use Vue, you don't really know the CSS of your child component and so you can't assume it's `block`.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use the @media query? You can show something on desktop and hide on mobile by using this css:

```
@media (max-width:1024px){
        .yourclassname {
            display:none;
        }
```

Comment: Well, that's the job of Tailwind CSS. It's all about writing CSS directly in your HTML.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about Tailwind. Just because you are used to do it that way, doesn't mean that it fits into the OP's use case.